# Create context menu in Adobe Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

Hi I am using Adobe Indesign. I need to create custom context menu and add script exceution for it. Is there any way to add context menu with or without Javascript

Comment: Yes. E.g. look at https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2482306

Comment: yes. but not exactly i need a menu in context menu. then how and where do i add my script

Comment: OK, have a look at this one: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/289129. You can run the script from the scripts panel or you can add it to start up scripts folder to make it a permanent feature